# Extending a java spring singleton abstract class with JdbcTemplate field

Tags: java, spring, oop, abstract-class, jdbctemplate

I am looking at this code base and I am trying to understand how it works or if it has code smell.

```
@Repository
@Scope("singleton")
public abstract class BaseDao {

  @Autowired
  protected JdbcTemplate jdbc;

}
```

```
@Repository
@Scope("singleton")
public class Dao1 extends BaseDao {

}

@Repository
@Scope("singleton")
public class Dao2 extends BaseDao {

}
```

My question is what happens when I extend the BaseDAO abstract class in Dao1 & Dao2, does spring create 2 jdbc templates, one for both, Dao1 & Dao2 or because BaseDAO is spring-singleton (I am aware this is different from Java singleton or singleton design pattern), it uses/shares the same jdbc template with all child classes once any child has created a jdbc template.

Would spring create a new jdbctemplate each time you use `@Autowired protected JdbcTemplate jdbc` or the same one?

EDIT: updated the question to remove confusing mentions of **session**.

Comment: There is no such thing as a SQL or JDBC session. And the same JdbcTemplate will be injected in both beans, since Spring beans, by default, ar singletons.

Comment: @JBNizet If I were to use a different JdbcTemplate for each Dao object (let's say there are 4 of them), would application actually create 4 connections to the sql-server one for each Dao object ?

Comment: No. The connection each would use would be the one bound to the current transaction.

Comment: I am not sure I follow, my understanding is everytime JdbcTemplate object is used for executing a SQL query, it requests a connection from the connection pool maintained by the implementation of DataSource interface.

Comment: Exactly, and it does that by calling https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DataSourceUtils.html#getConnection-javax.sql.DataSource-, which will return the connection bound to the current transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JB Nizet's comment above is the right answer, spring by default uses singleton scope and hence it would inject the same JdbcTemplate in both the classes, Dao1 & Dao2.